# how to print current page response when using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Eg.

```
describe 'xxx' do
  let() {}
  print page.response
  before {visit user_path(user)}
  print page.response
```

Is there any similar grammar to implement 'print page.response'? What's the correct way to debug when writing rspec?

Comment: Try `print response`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see what the page looks like at a particular point in time, use the `save_and_open_page` method from Capybara. For this to work properly, you'll need to add the `launchy` gem to your `Gemfile`, inside the "test" group there.

When you call `save_and_open_page` it will save the current page and then open it to show it to you in your browser.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `debugger` that comes from `byebug` gem. 
In `it` block and use `response.body` to check the response this will give you the response HTML.

If you are a beginner to rspec testing, you can follow [my article](https://medium.com/@abhishek.kanojia/getting-started-with-rails-testing-rspec-756678969e2a)  which may help you in writing specs.

```
describe 'xxx' do
  before { visit user_path(user) }
  it 'expect something' do
    debugger
  end
end
```

And in console check for `response.body` it should print current page response.

Comment: Response does not work. undefined local variable or method 'response' for Rspec::ExampleGroups::.....::Class. But page.body works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below:

```
print page.body
```